# Apache on CentOS 6 Unresponsive

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, service

Twice this morning, somewhere early this morning, and then again around 8-9AM, our Apache server was unresponsive, though the service showed as running. We reset it with service httpd restart, which seems to resolve the issue. Before this, our server has been up and functional for about three months.

I read another article and changed MaxClients and some other value to 512 from 256, as there was a "[error] server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting" showing, but that was at 9:05AM today. There wasn't one showing for the "crash" earlier this morning.

Here's some of the current error_log:

```
[Tue Mar 31 01:22:11 2015] [error] [client 192.187.126.162] script '/home/www/www.pixelark.com/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Mar 31 02:09:13 2015] [error] [client 198.252.44.11] File does not exist: /home/www/www.pixelark.com/www/player.vimeo.com
[Tue Mar 31 02:09:13 2015] [error] [client 198.252.44.11] File does not exist: /home/www/www.pixelark.com/www/player.vimeo.com
[Tue Mar 31 02:32:59 2015] [error] [client 188.165.233.228] File does not exist: /home/www/www.pixelark.com/www/calvarycch
[Tue Mar 31 02:34:29 2015] [error] [client 27.104.199.92] File does not exist: /home/www/www.pixelark.com/www/apple-touch-icon.png
[Tue Mar 31 02:37:19 2015] [error] [client 66.74.91.61] File does not exist: /home/www/www.pixelark.com/www/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
[Tue Mar 31 02:37:19 2015] [error] [client 66.74.91.61] File does not exist: /home/www/www.pixelark.com/www/apple-touch-icon.png
[Tue Mar 31 02:57:31 2015] [error] [client 173.184.225.8] File does not exist: /home/www/www.pixelark.com/www/apple-touch-icon.png
[Tue Mar 31 07:36:29 2015] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Mar 31 07:36:29 2015] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Tue Mar 31 07:36:29 2015] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Mar 31 07:36:29 2015] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Tue Mar 31 07:36:29 2015] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Mar 31 07:36:29 2015] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Mar 31 07:36:30 2015] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Tue Mar 31 07:36:30 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Mar 31 07:44:21 2015] [error] [client 68.6.150.73] File does not exist: /home/www/www.pixelark.com/www/apple-touch-icon-120x120-precomposed.png


[Tue Mar 31 08:23:02 2015] [error] [client 172.56.0.75] File does not exist: /home/www/www.pixelark.com/www/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
[Tue Mar 31 08:23:02 2015] [error] [client 172.56.0.75] File does not exist: /home/www/www.pixelark.com/www/apple-touch-icon.png
[Tue Mar 31 08:45:35 2015] [error] [client 173.208.203.138] File does not exist: /home/www/www.pixelark.com/www/readme.asp
[Tue Mar 31 08:56:53 2015] [error] [client 184.176.137.140] File does not exist: /home/www/www.pixelark.com/www/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
[Tue Mar 31 08:56:53 2015] [error] [client 184.176.137.140] File does not exist: /home/www/www.pixelark.com/www/apple-touch-icon.png
[Tue Mar 31 09:05:13 2015] [error] server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting
[Tue Mar 31 09:11:54 2015] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Mar 31 09:11:55 2015] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Tue Mar 31 09:11:55 2015] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Mar 31 09:11:55 2015] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Tue Mar 31 09:11:55 2015] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Mar 31 09:11:55 2015] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Mar 31 09:11:55 2015] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Tue Mar 31 09:11:55 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Mar 31 09:17:13 2015] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Mar 31 09:17:13 2015] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Tue Mar 31 09:17:13 2015] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Mar 31 09:17:14 2015] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Tue Mar 31 09:17:14 2015] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Mar 31 09:17:14 2015] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Mar 31 09:17:14 2015] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Tue Mar 31 09:17:14 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Mar 31 09:20:04 2015] [error] [client 107.143.147.89] File does not exist: /home/www/www.pixelark.com/www/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
[Tue Mar 31 09:20:05 2015] [error] [client 107.143.147.89] File does not exist: /home/www/www.pixelark.com/www/apple-touch-icon.png
[Tue Mar 31 09:23:15 2015] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Mar 31 09:21:07 2015] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Tue Mar 31 09:21:07 2015] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Mar 31 09:21:08 2015] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Tue Mar 31 09:21:08 2015] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Mar 31 09:21:08 2015] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Mar 31 09:21:09 2015] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Tue Mar 31 09:21:09 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Mar 31 09:21:12 2015] [error] [client 119.74.155.16] File does not exist: /home/www/www.pixelark.com/www/cscc, referer: http://pixelark.com/cscc/recent/mobile/mobile
[Tue Mar 31 09:24:18 2015] [error] [client 119.74.155.16] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/www/www.pixelark.com/db.php on line 9
[Tue Mar 31 09:24:18 2015] [error] [client 119.74.155.16] PHP Warning:  mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /home/www/www.pixelark.com/db.php on line 10
[Tue Mar 31 09:24:18 2015] [error] [client 119.74.155.16] PHP Warning:  mysql_query() [<a href='function.mysql-query'>function.mysql-query</a>]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/www/www.pixelark.com/www/mobile_controller/index.php on line 23
[Tue Mar 31 09:24:18 2015] [error] [client 119.74.155.16] PHP Warning:  mysql_query() [<a href='function.mysql-query'>function.mysql-query</a>]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/www/www.pixelark.com/www/mobile_controller/index.php on line 23
[Tue Mar 31 09:24:18 2015] [error] [client 119.74.155.16] PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/www/www.pixelark.com/www/mobile_controller/index.php on line 29
```

Comment: Could you please fix the formatting of your log excerpt?

Comment: A couple things to note: there is a long gap in the log after 2:57AM. Also, our swap file is approximately 8GB, while our physical memory is 16GB. Could this have been the cause? Is there a way we can check if it was? Again, this server has been functioning just fine for about three months.

Comment: Steven, to check for issues with Swap, use a utility like `top`. Many basic sysadmin books will show you how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need more information to debug this, such as the number of clients connected at the time and which pages are being used at the time of the freeze.

Often, MaxClients is only reached when an application-side bug is having problems-- clients will request a page, and the application will take a long time to respond back to the client. In my experience, this problem creeps up when a bug is introduced by a recent code change, or when the application code depends on a database or filesystem, and that database or filesystem is slow or unavailable, etc. It is rarely a problem in Apache itself. There are many possible application-side causes.

If the bottleneck is a filesystem or database, you may have made the problem worse by raising MaxClients from 256 to 512, because now you have twice as many clients connecting to the problematic resource.

To provide more visibility into the problem from the Apache perspective:

1. Look in the Apache access log to determine which pages are most popular.
2. Enable [mod_status](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_status.html) which will print server performance information, and will print information about all current sessions. Enable `ExtendedStatus`, as recommended by the section *Using server-status to troubleshoot*. For security reasons, restrict access to a safe set of IP addresses.
3. Monitor the status page at http://your.server.name/server-status?auto . You can do this via a browser, or from the commandline using a command like `service httpd fullstatus` (see https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/use-httpd-fullstatus-to-monitor-apache-status/ for an example). You can also capture this information to a log file, with a command like `service httpd fullstatus > /var/log/httpd.status.log` or `service httpd fullstatus | logger -t httpd-status`, and put this into cron, or log using Cacti, Splunk or another program.

This should provide you much more information as to the state of the system leading up to the time of the freeze.

Comment: Thank you Stefan. I'm working on adding mod_status. I'm getting a 404 error when I have access to the /server-status page though, as if it doesn't exist. Any ideas?

Comment: Check your access and error log and look for the 404 error, and then see if the page mentioned in the logfile matches what you set in the configuration file. You will need to restart or reload Apache.

Comment: So it appears they're running webmin on this server. The sites are stored in /home/www, so I just updated the apache config, but to no avail. This is what I have in it (the IP was one I was access the address from:

' <Location /home/www/www.pixelark.com/www/server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from pixelark.com
 Allow from 108.13.255.157
</Location> '

Comment: I can't for the life of me edit the above post correctly, sorry.

Comment: This was all very helpful, thank you. Turns out it was probably a DOS attack.

Comment: I'm glad you found enough information to help out.